# Function template specialization for derivation of a specific type

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

```
class base
{
};

class derived
{
};

template<class T> void foo() {}


int main()
{
    foo<int>();
    foo<derived>();
}
```

I want to specialize `foo` for T = derivation of `base`. Is this possible or do I need to specialize for `base` itself?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine boost::enable_if and boost::is_base_of, as is documented [in the manual for boost::enable_if](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html).

```
template <class T>
T foo(typename enable_if<boost::is_base_of<base,T> >::type* dummy = 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use [boost type traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_base_of.html) (or if feeling brave, look at the source of that library).

At compile time you can detect if a type inherits from another type and so choose an appropriate implementation.